# WebBrowser Control blocking ajax

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm using webbrowser control embeded in a winform in my C# app to do some scraping. The content I'm looking for is dynamically loaded with ajax. However, when I navigate to the page the content won't load unless I have no other code running. I tried doing

```
while(webbrowser1.isBusy);
```

But that's not helping. I also tried pausing the program for a few second to give it time to load

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

but it's still not loading. If I navigate to the page with no code following, it loads fine. I'm not really sure how I could split this into threads. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you handling the Document.Complete event at all?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I got it using a time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while(webbrowser1.isBusy); and Thread.Sleep(2000); would block the main message pump, and ajax requires a message pump for asynchronous callback. I suggest you to start a timer in DocumentComplete to poll the web page regularly until you think the page is complete. Remember to stop the timer in BeforeNavigate2